# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания и объяснить их?!

Tags: пунктуация

Я знаю(,) аргументация (-) это процесс(,) который должен происходить в определенной последовательности и развития.

(")Белые акации будут цвести в лунные ночи страстные(,) луч морями зальет золотой реку(,) и ивы(,) и круче(...)(") / В.Сосюра /

Необходимо не только правильно расставить знаки препинания, но и объяснить их постановку.

Answer (score 3):

*Я знаю: аргументация - это процесс, который должен происходить в определенной последовательности.* (Не понимаю, к чему относится и" развития"). Двоеточие стоит между частями бессоюзного предложения (вторая часть поясняет первую),тире  - между подлежащим и сказуемым, запятая  - перед придаточной частью.

Во втором предложении не вижу смысла. Или опечатки?
У Соссюры :

*Били акациё будут цвисти в мисячни ночи жагучи;
 проминь морями заллє золотой ричку, и ивы и кручи.*

Кажется, это должно быть вот так: *Белые акации будут цвести в лунные ночи страстные,
 луч морями зальет золотом реку, и ивы, и кручи...* 
Первая запятая - между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения (у автора - точка с запятой, почему бы не оставить и в переводе?), вторая и третья разделяет однородные члены.